# MySQL: Finding id's in separate tables with identical groups of records

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables with some of the records having the same sub groups of information, but both having different id values. Below is an example where I have a table of `actors` from `movies` and `plays`.

I would like to query these two tables such that I get a pair of `movie_id`, `play_id` values that have all the same actors (i.e. have `first_name = given_name` and `last_name = family_name` for each record with the same `id`).

What would be the appropriate query to accomplish this?

```
TABLE: movie_actors
| movie_id | first_name | last_name |
|----------+------------+-----------|
|        1 |       mary |   johnson |
|        1 |       john |     smith |
|        2 |        tom |  anderson |

TABLE: play_actors
|  play_id | given_name | family_name |
|----------+------------+-------------|
|       23 |       mary |     johnson |
|       23 |       john |       smith |
|       31 |       marc |     anthony |


DESIRED OUTPUT:
| movie_id | play_id |
|----------+---------|
|        1 |      23 |
```

Comment: Why isn't `2, 31` included in the desired output?

Comment: sorry, I will edit it so that 2 and 31 have different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` in subqueries to get all the actors as a single column. Then join the subqueries based on this.

```
SELECT movie_id, play_id
FROM (SELECT movie_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name, '-', last_name) ORDER BY first_name, last_name) AS actors
      FROM movie_actors
      GROUP BY movie_id) AS m
JOIN (SELECT play_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(given_name, '-', family_name) ORDER BY given_name, family_name) AS actors
      FROM play_actors
      GROUP BY play_id) AS p
ON m.actors = p.actors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `movie_id`, `play_id`
FROM `movie_actors`
INNER JOIN `play_actors`
ON STRCMP(`first_name`,`given_name`) = 0
    AND STRCMP(`last_name`,`family_name`) = 0
```

Note that the values for `first_name` must exactly match `given_name`, likewise for `last_name` and `family_name`.

If you want to restrict for e.g. the `movie_id` just add a where clause specifying the desired value at the end of the query like:

```
WHERE `movie_id` = ** ID **
```